# Grabbing Switch Statements from For loops

Tags: c, for-loop, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i, party;
char x = ' ';
float total = 0, perCost = 0;
main(){

            switch (toupper(x)) {
                case 'A':
                    printf("Combo A: Friend Chicken with slaw [price: 4.25]");
                    perCost = 4.24;             
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    printf("Combo B: Roast beef with mashed potato [price: 5.75]");
                    perCost = 5.75;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    printf("Combo A: Fish and chips [price: 5.25]");
                    perCost = 5.25;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    printf("Combo A: soup and salad [price: 3.74]");
                    perCost = 3.75;
                    break;
                default:
                    perCost = 0;
                    break;
            }

    printf("Enter Party Total: ");
    scanf("%d", &party);
    for (i = 0; i < party; i++) {
            printf("Enter item ordered [A/B/C/D/X]: ");
            scanf("%c%*c", &x);
    }
    total = total + perCost;
    printf("%f\n", total);
}
```

What is causing my programming to not grab from the switch statement?

Comment: This is C, no matter how you look at it and even if you include a C++ header. Retagged and edited the header out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the given code, when the execution first come to the `switch()` the value of `x` is `' '` , so the by executing the `switch()` gives `perCost = 0` executing the default condition in `switch()` make you believe that the program din grab the `switch()`.(Note that the execution never come back to here again)

To achieve what you supposed, give the `switch()` inside the `for (i = 0; i < party; i++)` loop, specifically, below your `scanf`.

Note that `total = total + perCost;` is misplaced, as of now, it wont calculate the total but only gives the `perCost` of the last combo you ordered.This is also supposed to be inside the loop.

You need a `#include <cctype.h>` in your program.

Comment: oh righttt i forgot <cctype.h> thats the only reason why this wasn't working. haha %c%*c is to get rid of the enter key thats in the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I think your switch statement needs to be inside the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < party; i++) {
    printf("Enter item ordered [A/B/C/D/X]: ");
    scanf("%c%*c", &x);


    //  Put your switch here.
    switch (toupper(x)) {
            case 'A':
                printf("Combo A: Friend Chicken with slaw [price: 4.25]");
                perCost = 4.24;             
                break;
            case 'B':
                printf("Combo B: Roast beef with mashed potato [price: 5.75]");
                perCost = 5.75;
                break;
            case 'C':
                printf("Combo A: Fish and chips [price: 5.25]");
                perCost = 5.25;
                break;
            case 'D':
                printf("Combo A: soup and salad [price: 3.74]");
                perCost = 3.75;
                break;
            default:
                perCost = 0;
                break;
        }



    total = total + perCost;  // Move this into the loop.

}
```

Comment: Yes. As it stands, your switch is being evaluated only once before you enter the loop, when `x` is `' '`, and never again.

Comment: He should also be putting 'total = total + perCost' inside the loop and after the switch.

Comment: this still doesn't calculate the perCost.. it does exactly what my program does.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the `scanf` is properly reading the input? Try printing out the letters after you read them.

Answer (score 0):

Because the order of your switche statemnt is wrong... it needs to be inside the loop after the scanf;

More importantly i think you are mixing two things up... .1) what needs to be displayed and 2)  what needs to be processed... Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i, party;
    char x = ' ';
    float total = 0, perCost = 0;

    printf("Enter Party Total: ");
    scanf("%d", &party);

    printf("Combo A: Friend Chicken with slaw [price: 4.25]");
    printf("Combo B: Roast beef with mashed potato [price: 5.75]");
    printf("Combo A: Fish and chips [price: 5.25]");
    printf("Combo A: soup and salad [price: 3.74]");

    for (i = 0; i < party; i++) {
         printf("Enter item ordered [A/B/C/D]: ");
         scanf("%c%*c", &x);

         switch (toupper(x)) {
                case 'A':
                    perCost = 4.24;             
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    perCost = 5.75;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    perCost = 5.25;
                    break;
                case 'D':

                    perCost = 3.75;
                    break;
                default:
                    perCost = 0;
                    break;
            }

            total = total + perCost;
    }
    printf("Total is: %f\n", total);
}
```

Comment: this still doesn't calculate the total.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're ever redirecting logic back to your switch. Try moving your switch chunk into a function and calling it from your for loop. Or, just stick it in the for loop after you receive input.